# When can we say $ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{\sin x} \int_{0}^{\sin x} {x}^2 f(x) dx = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

I encountered this problem while trying to solve a larger problem involving oscillation in a nonlinear system.

What conditions need to be applied on $f(x)$ such that,
$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{\sin x} \int_{0}^{\sin x} {u}^2 f(u) \:\textrm{d}u = 0  \:\:\textrm{holds.}$$

We are given that the function $f(x)$ is bounded, monotonically decreasing, and non-negative. Is this enough to guarantee that the condition above holds?

Can we relax the bounded condition and still have it be true?

Comment: The equivalence $\sin x \sim x$ as $x \to 0$  might be useful.

Comment: Bounded and non-negative is enough, since these constraints ensure that the given integral is non-negative but bounded by $$\frac{1}{\sin x}\int_{0}^{\sin x}M z^2\,dz = \frac{M}{3}\sin^2(x) \to 0 $$ as $x\to 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we have boundedness, $0 \leq f(x) \leq C$, it will be true.  (You don't need $f(x)$ to be non-negative, just bounded below by some number).  Denote $L$ as the limit, then

$L \leq \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{\sin x}\int_{0}^{\sin x}Ct^{2} dt=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{C(\sin x)^{3}}{3\sin x} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{C (\sin x)^{2}}{3}=0$.

The lowerbound is proven similarly.

**To answer the updated question**:

Using the same argument, if we relax the boundedness of f(x), as long as for some $\epsilon>0$, **$x^{2-\epsilon}f(x)$ is bounded** in an open interval containing $0$, then the limit equals $0$.

If $x^{2}f(x)$ is not bounded then we can construct a counterexample.

Say $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^{2.5}}$, so that the integral in the limit exists.

Then $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}} \frac{1}{\sin x}\int_{0}^{\sin x}\frac{t^{2}}{t^{2.5}} dt=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}  \frac{2\sqrt{\sin x}}{\sin x} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}}  \frac{2}{\sqrt{\sin x}} = \infty$$

Comment: Thanks, this helps, but can this be realised using monotonically decreasing and non-negative? i.e say f(x) = 1/x and similar family of functions

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

As other have said, if $f$ is non-negative and bounded above, it will work. Another way to see this is L'hopital's rule

Comment: Is boundedness required for L'hopital?

Comment: L'Hospital's Rule applies only when $f $ is continuous.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh good point